# How to Disable SYSENTER Syscall Support and Only Use int $0x80 in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls, sysenter

I am trying to disable `SYSENTER` syscall support and let all system calls fall back through `int $0x80` interrupts in Linux without any use of ptrace.

I have found two ways：

1. Disable VDSO entirely by modifying `/proc/sys/vm/vdso_enabled` file to 0
2. Modify `/usr/src/linux/arch/x86/vdso/vdso32-setup.c`

Modifying the VDSO(Virtual Dynamic Shared Object) shall be the method in my approach, but I do not know which line(s) to modify. Could someone give me any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to trap system call so I want to disable sysentry to make all system call go through int 0x80 to make it easier to be traped

Comment: This is what [`ptrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) is for.  It is arcane and poorly documented, but it works for `gdb`, `strace`, and UML, so I am confident it can do what you need.  (Specifically, look at what the `PTRACE_SYSCALL` operation does.)

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood me.  You don't use `ptrace` to disable `sysenter`.  You use `ptrace` to *trap system calls*, thus eliminating any *need* to disable `sysenter`.  Or build a custom kernel, in fact.